# How to queue jQuery ajax requests?

Tags: jquery

I've been doing a lot of searching and don't think I can find what I am looking for.

I have a system similar to how twitter works where you need to add (or follow in Twitter) multiple people at a click of a button.

So for example every time I click an "Add" button below, it makes an AJAX request to add them to the database.

```
<ul>
    <li>Ben <a href="#" onclick="return addPerson(1);">Add</a></li>
    <li>Sarah <a href="#" onclick="return addPerson(2);">Add</a></li>
    <li>Chantelle <a href="#" onclick="return addPerson(3);">Add</a></li>
    <li>Alan <a href="#" onclick="return addPerson(4);">Add</a></li>
</ul>
```

Now if I click the add button for each person, one after another, I don't think queuing one ajax request for each person would be a good use of resources. Plus it would be slow.

What I'm thinking is maybe a delay or something along those lines after I click each "Add" button. So it records all the ID's of the people I click, and sends one ajax request for all the people clicked.

Is there an existing script or can you recommend how I could do this?

Comment: Possible: a global `boolean` variable to check if the AJAX is already running; if so, use a `setInterval()` to keep checking until the variable is reset after the AJAX runs `complete()`... Not tested, but it should work in theory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would something like this do the trick?

```
var sendDelay;
var peopleToSend = [];
addPerson = function(id) {
   if (sendDelay!=null) {
      clearTimeout(sendDelay);  // Clear timeout
   }
   sendDelay=setTimeout(addPersonDelayComplete,2000);  // Reset timeout
   peopleToSend.push(id);  // Add person to array
}

addPersonDelayComplete = function() {
   // Send the people in peopleToSend in a single ajax call here
   peopleToSend.length = 0;  // Reset the array
 }
```

Comment: What a legend! Really appreciate that and it works out of the box!

Comment: but this solution does not consider the state of AJAX. What if the AJAX is still loading previous request?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor - You can have multiple ajax requsets in flight at the same time.  The OP didn't ask to limit it to only one ajax request.  They asked to implement a delay and when the delay passes without any new people being added, then fire off the ajax request with all new names collected since the last request.